# Is there a way to query an OpenBSD package by description?

Tags: package-management, openbsd

In OpenBSD's package manager, I was hoping it was possible to search by keyword in the packages comment/description section, not just by package name.

This is for the remote repository listed in `$PKG_PATH`. `pkg_info -Q name` searches the package name on the remote repository, but not in the description.

Is there a way to search by partial keyword in the package's description for all packages on a remote repo.?

If this is not possible, than how do people search/discover new packages besides the package file name? For example: give me all the packages on the remote repo. with the word `language` in the comment section.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking too simple, but `pkg_info | grep <keyword>`?

Comment: @Zwans That searches the installed packages. I'm searching the packages on a remove mirror. That's why I used `-Q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `pkg_mgr` port ("user-friendly package browser and manager"). I've never used it though.

It's currently not possible to do this through `pkg_info -Q` as the "query" that it takes is interpreted strictly as a package name, or part thereof.

Personally, I have `/usr/ports` checked out from CVS and use either

```
$ grep "something" /usr/ports/INDEX
```

or

```
$ find /usr/ports -type f -name 'DESCR*' -exec grep "something" {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ports tree installed, then a good way of searching for packages based on keywords is to use make. For example, using the word "language" as the search key

```
   $ cd /usr/ports
   $ make search key=language
```

will produce a useful listing of relevant ports/packages.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PkgFind) mentions `pkg_info -Q` and `pkglocate`:

```
$ pkg_info -Q pkglocate
$ pkglocate pkg_info
```

Comment: The question already talks about `pkg_info -Q` (i.e., the OP already knows about it).  If the FAQ contains information relevant to this question, please copy it into your post.  I don’t understand what *answer to the question* you are offering. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.